# Wav file tranfer sockets

Tags: sockets, wav, python-3.3

**Solution (in a way): <strike>I just added atime sleep although the half file still got corrupted but at least now i transfered all the 1.19 mb</strike> . 
Removing completely base64 seems to be the answer :D**

I am trying to create a script where a user can tranfer a wav file . 
This is my current code both client side and server side . The problem is
that my data is corrupted at the end .

Also when i see all the data transfered i am closing the server
Ps. I that file is  bad name variable but i am using it only now during the tests

Thanks in advance .

Client Side:

```
class SockThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def create_r(self, filename):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.filename = filename
    def run(self):
        self.sock.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8000))
        wf = open(self.filename, 'rb')
        print("OK")
        for line in wf:

            self.sock.send(base64.b64encode(line))

        wf.close()
        print("OK")
```

Server Side:

```
file = open("sample.wav", "wb")
self.connection = True
while self.connection is True:
try:
    data = self.socket.recv(1024)
    print(data)
    file.write(base64.b64decode(data))
except:
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to read the entire file from the socket and then `b64decode` it, doing it in chunks of 1024 byte may not produce the same result.

Comment: That didn't work , the file is no more playable in that way .